# How to get all values by wildcard key in redis

Tags: go, redis, redigo

Let say I have following data in redis:

```
key               value

user-1-xxxx       data1

user-1-yyyy       data2

user-1-tttt       data3
```

So, can I get all above records by wildcard `user-1-*` (including the keys and values).

I tried `KEYS user-1-*` , but it only give all the keys, not their values.

If it is not support wildcard searching, can you recommend a way to store this kind of data.

I am using golang redigo by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to structure your data into a hash instead of single keys.

```
> HSET user-1 xxxx data1
> HSET user-1 yyyy data2
> HSET user-1 tttt data3
```

If you want to get everything on the user run `HGETALL user-1` but if you just want to get a specific part, go for `HGET user-1 xxx`.

Comment: @ stockholmux i used this like `reply, err := conn.Cmd("HGETALL", cacheKey).Map()` but here i am able to get only one record while i want all records which have same `cacheKey`, could you plz help me to out of this.

Comment: @saddam Each key can only hold one "record"

Comment: @ stockholmux thank you for your reply, one question here-  can we use filter on colomns like search on date to get records.

Comment: @saddam nope. Redis doesn't work that way. If you have needs for filtering/searching, you should look at RediSearch (Redis Search engine)

Answer (score 0):

Redis isn't designed for looking up data by value. You can either index the data yourself (see https://redis.io/topics/indexes) or use a search engine for that, such as http://redisearch.io.